# How can i show this infimum equality $A_{s-}^{-1}=\inf\{t\geq 0: A_t\geq s\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $s\mapsto A_s$ be an increasing right continuous function, $s\geq 0$. Then define $A_s^{-1}:=\inf\{t\geq 0: A_t>s\}$ with the convention $\inf\{\emptyset\}=\infty$. By definition the map $s\mapsto A_s^{-1}$ in increasing so one can define $A_{s-}^{-1}:=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} A_{s-h}^{-1}$ the left limit. I want to show that $A_{s-}^{-1}=\inf\{t\geq 0: A_t\geq s\}$

Unfortunately I don't see how to do this, I thought about rewriting $\inf\{t\geq 0: A_t\geq s\}=A_s^{-1}\wedge \inf\{t\geq 0: A_t=s\}$ but this does not help me. Then I remarked that $A_{s-h}^{-1}=\inf\{ t\geq 0: A_t+h>s\}\leq\inf\{t\geq 0: A_t\geq s\}$ hence I would say $lim_{h\rightarrow 0} A_{s-h}^{-1}\leq \inf\{t\geq 0: A_t\geq s\}$ but the other inequality is still not clear. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A_t$ is right continuous and increasing it is upper semi continuous. This means that
$\{t\ge 0:A_t<s\}$ is open and $\{t\ge 0:A_t\ge s\}$ is closed.
For any sequence $s_n\uparrow s$ we have
$$
\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{t\ge 0:A_t> s_n\}=\{t\ge 0:A_t\ge s\}\,
$$
and also
$$
\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{t\ge 0:A_t\color{red}{\ge} s_n\}=\{t\ge 0:A_t\ge s\}\,.
$$
The second relation holds because we can assume wlog that the sequence $s_n$ is strictly increasing.
Since
$$
A^{-1}_{s-}=\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}\inf\{t\ge 0:A_t> s_n\}
$$
we must show the claim $\stackrel{!}{=}$ in
\begin{align}
\inf\{t\ge 0:A_t\ge s\}&=
\inf\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{t\ge 0:A_t> s_n\}\\
&=\inf\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{t\ge 0:A_t\color{red}{\ge}s_n\}\\
&\stackrel{!}{=}\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}\inf\{t\ge 0:A_t> s_n\}\,.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Proof. Since
$$
\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{t\ge 0:A_t> s_n\}
\subset\{t\ge 0:A_t> s_m\} 
$$
holds for all $m$ we have
$$
\inf\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{t\ge 0:A_t> s_n\}
\ge\inf\{t\ge 0:A_t> s_m\} 
$$
so that the inequality $\ge$ in (1) follows.
For the other inequality we observe that
$$
\inf\{t\ge 0:A_t\color{red}{\ge}s_n\}\le \inf\{t\ge 0:A_t>s_n\}
$$
so that it is enough to show
$$\tag{2}
\inf\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{t\ge 0:A_t\color{red}{\ge}s_n\}
\le \sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\inf\{t\ge 0:A_t\color{red}{\ge}s_n\}\,.
$$
Since the sets
$\{t\ge 0:A_t\color{red}\ge s_n\}$ are closed every
infimum of such a set is in the set. Then
$\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}\inf\{t\ge 0:A_t\color{red}{\ge}s_n\}$ is in every
$$
\inf\{t\ge 0:A_t\color{red}{\ge}s_m\}
$$
since that set is closed for every $m\,.$ Therefore, that supremum is in the
intersection of all those sets. It follows that
this supremum must be larger or equal than the infimum on the LHS of (2).

Comment: Where did i wrote this claim?

Comment: In your title and in the sentence that "I want so show that...".

Comment: No I have there $A_{s-}^{-1}$ which is the left limit